# Why are my javascript files not being found in assetic?

Tags: javascript, symfony, assetic

I am using Twig as my template, utilizing a layout, in which I have a javascript block

```
...
    {% block javascripts %}
        {% javascripts
            '@jquery'
            '@bootstrap_js' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
    {% endblock %}


</body>
```

In a content template, I have

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% javascripts '@AppBundle/Resources/public/index/*' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is my assetic section of the config.yml

```
assetic:
debug:          true
use_controller: false
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
assets:
    bootstrap_js:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
    bootstrap_css:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css
        filters:
            [cssrewrite]
    bootstrap_glyphicons_ttf:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
        output:
            "../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"
    bootstrap_glyphicons_eot:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
        output:
            "../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"
    bootstrap_glyphicons_svg:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
        output:
            "../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg"
    bootstrap_glyphicons_woff:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
        output:
            "../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
    jquery:
        inputs:
            - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

Everything else works fine, except for the files under `@AppBundle/Resources/public/index/*`. I run `assetic:dump` for my environment, everything goes smoothly, but I keep getting a 404 HTML dump underneath the script element for `@AppBundle/Resources/public/index/*`

```
<script src="/logbook/web/js/431d650.js">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>An Error Occurred: Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Oops! An Error Occurred</h1>
    <h2>The server returned a "404 Not Found".</h2>

    <div>
        Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred.
        We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
</script>
```

Something is broken, apparently, but I cannot figure out what???

Answer (score 0):

I did also have some issues using assetic in the past and I wrote down a way how I got it work. Maybe it would help you if you'd try to execute the following command first before dumping the assetic stuff:

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink web
```

Comment: I ran that and the dump, and all it did was create symlinks within web/bundles directory to `@AppBundle/Resources/public/index/*`. Unfortunately I'm still getting 404 errors for files under that directory.

Comment: Will it work if you'd try to refer to a specific file like for example: {% javascripts 'bundles/app/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js' %}

Comment: No. Same result. I feel like it's just the path reference doesn't match up. For some reason only stuff that is in the composer directory ever works.

Comment: That's what I guess as well... there's might be something wrong with the paths...